# CORS error in localhost using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, cors

I have a API running under localhost that receive POST request to create a account, so i created a simple "HTML" page using ajax jquery to call this API, see:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/contas/",
            data: '{"email":"' + var_email + '"}',
            success: function () {
                new Noty({text: 'Conta criada com sucesso', theme: 'relax', type: 'info'}).show()
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

But i got always

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My API (spring-boot) already have the @CrossOrigin:

```
@CrossOrigin(value = "*", origins = "*", maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*", methods =
        {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.POST})
```

But i think this is not needed if request is from same HOST (localhost).